# Accessing users data from client side in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm having trouble with setting up a method to access data about my user collection.

What I want to do is to be able to build a list of user, visible to the currently logged in user, with a restrained access to their informations.

For that, I do :

// client side

```
{{#each talker}}
  <div class="span5 talker-card well">
    <span><b>{{talkname}}</b></span>
  </div>
{{/each}}


if(Meteor.isClient){
  Template.talkers.rendered = function(){
    Deps.autorun(function(){
      Meteor.subscribe("usersData");
    });
  };
  Template.talkers.helpers({
    talker: function(){
      return Meteor.Users;
      // return EJSON.stringify(Meteor.user());
      // return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    }
  });
}
```

// Server side

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.publish("usersData", function(){
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields : {'profile.talkname' : 1}});
  });
}
```

The problem is that absolutely nothing appears, the helper return nothing. I guess the problem is that I'm not getting the data from the good var client side, but I do not know in wuch one I can get them !

Can someone explain that to me ?

THanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The helper is returning `Meteor.Users` which is a typo of a collection name, but not a cursor. Try `Meteor.users.find()` instead.